# Filter search in angular-material table is not working in raw data

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is the raw data. Then I am using date pipe '| date' to convert the timestamp to readable date. I am using material table and i want to filter it on search bar. but it only filters the raw date. Ho to fix this?

```
{
    userDate: '2018-09-28 16:31:44.626'
}

{{ userDate | date }}
```

Comment: What is the end result you are trying to accomplish? Can you post a minimal example of your code including the component and template?

Comment: <ng-container matColumnDef="productTimeStamp">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Time Stamp </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{ product.productTimeStamp | date }} </td>
    </ng-container>

Comment: I want to filter by date in the format of date pipe. but the only reconizeable data is the raw data.

Comment: applyFilter(filterValue: string) { //serach engine
    this.productArray.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (this.productArray.paginator) {
      this.productArray.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }